# How to identify mute/unmute click - SOLVE

Tags: android, togglebutton

my problem is following:
I want indentify (the keyevent) when the user click in the mute/unmute button and so change  the satus of toggle button.

One image to understand better: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-yHjyvtCiyac/Ul6uQz_Ga2I/AAAAAAAAAiY/Ug06zyq7_Vg/w619-h81-no/volumebar.jpg

How do this?

Thanks.

Sorry for my english. I use Google Translator for do this >.<

---

Update: The mute/unmute button in XML file :

```
<ToggleButton 
android:id="@+id/toggle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/audiobtn"
android:textOn="" 
android:textOff="" />
```

Last Update: The problem was solved using the BroadcastReceiver class. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the mute button in your UI ?

Comment: How so? I don't uderstand what you mean.

Comment: Where is the mute button?

Comment: Oh yes. Is on the activity screen.

Comment: Post your xml for activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Toggle Button**

add this line in toggle button xml

```
android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
```

Now in your activity class set this listener as

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        // set image for on state 
    } else {
      // set image for off state 
    }
}
```

More info for Toggle button can be find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

**For simple button**

**Step 1** Create object on your button
 Button muteBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mute_btn);

**Step 2** Create the click listener of this button and change it to pressed/non pressed state using a boolean which stores its state like this.

```
boolean muteBtnSelection;

muteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (muteBtnSelection) {

                muteBtnSelection=false;

                // set yout image for  mutebtn_pressed
                muteBtn.setBackground(R.drawable.mutebtn_pressed);

            } else {
                muteBtnSelection=true;

                // set yout image for  mutebtn_not_pressed
                muteBtn.setBackground(R.drawable.mutebtn_not_pressed);

            }



        }
    });
```

in this way you can toggle between pressed and non pressed state.

Comment: Yes. It's works. I've done this.  But now I want change the toogle status when the user click here (the region contoured of red): https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-yHjyvtCiyac/Ul6uQz_Ga2I/AAAAAAAAAiY/Ug06zyq7_Vg/w619-h81-no/volumebar.jpg

Comment: Do you understood now?

Comment: in that you can select this as an answer.